# Reading stdin as fast as possible

Tags: c++, optimization, io

I've been strugling with a problem of reading from standard input as fast as possible. My task is to do a few ad hoc operations with input integers. The direct problem is a sequence of integers separated with spaces and with an EOF as a flag indicating an end of the input. I've already used a

`while (cin>>a) {
    //here are the operations
   }`

but that's not fast enough. I've heard that writing my own function reading only integers might be a way but I've got no idea how to implement that kind of function. Do u know anything about that?
 So what is a faster way of reading standard input in C++? Please write, because that's the solutions for every single project for anyone who yearns for a really fast program...
Thank U in advance and I'm waiting for Your response!

Comment: Not fast enough for what? How much faster do you need?

Comment: I've got to implement a program reading a sequence of 10^7 characters up to 10^9 each. And I've got a lot of operations to do on a single data. That's the reason why I'd like to know if there's a more efficient way of reading data...

Comment: " And I've got a lot of operations to do on a single data." - this sounds more like it's not the I/O that is hindering???

Comment: Try to define the window of the buffer you can read before loosing samples from it, this way you'll see if your operations are making you loose samples from the buffer.

Comment: Explain to me, plase what do You mean by 'hindering'?

Comment: @claudiordgz If you mean a sync_with_stdio(false) function - yes I can. But the pearson  who made the task told that a better way of using any form of 'cin' is implementing own reading function. That the problem I've got no idea how to handle. do U have any idea of solving that kind of a problem?

Comment: @vladimir1923, We use pure ansi C and DMATransfers to do those kind of operations. According to what I read in the link from Mats Petersson yeah, you'll end up syncing and using scanf. Allocate a buffer and start reading to it in C.

Comment: @vladimir1923: It's _really_ rare when that's true, but in those astoundingly rare cases, I use this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6f25f5a74a7cdd3  It's fast, but _very_ unsafe, and is liable to crash if any input is malformed.  DO NOT USE IN REAL CODE

Comment: So can I assume that using scanf is visibly faster than using cin? And will scanf work fine with cin.sync_with_stdio(false) well?

Comment: And one more question - when can I use cin.sync_with_stdio(false) and when I mustn't?

Comment: @vladimir1923:  What is the use of using DMA transfers with `cin`?  I could understand DMA with file transfers, but there may be such a huge time gap between key presses that override any performance gained by a DMA transfer.

Comment: @darxsys, any C++ compiler worth it's salt will use `operator<<` that is as fast (or faster) that `scanf(3)` (doesn't have to interpret format gunk at runtime, for one). And getting the data from disk will be slower than that, anyway.

Comment: @vladimir1923, *measure* before digging in. You might end up speeding up something that takes 1% of the runtime.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, if it is *keypresses*, entering the data mentioned will take some 60 *hours* for a fast typist.

Comment: @vonbrand, I can enter several pages of numbers into Microsoft Word, and other GUI applications that use character messages before 60 hours. (That's at least 2 days of continuous typing).  The OP hasn't mentioned the size of the incoming data.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, OP talks about 10^7 numbers...

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes, one more time - I've got a sequence of unsigned integers up to 10^9. The sequence is not longer than 10^7. Of course Your right that reading isn't the biggest problem but if the algoritym later on in the program is of complexity O(n) - I've got to make many comparisons and adding, subtracting and passing these values to some other variables, reading becomes crucial in making the execution time shorter. On the other hand, the test is not realted to putting manualy the values the the runtime, the way is iedone.com style. So first the sequence is passed then run.

Comment: @vonbrand From my experience, scanf proved to be much faster usually (algorithm solving for example). With gcc. Maybe I am wrong...

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two bottlenecks, one is out of the control of your program.

**Bottleneck 1 - Input into your program.**
The first bottleneck is obtaining the data from the input source.  Whether it be disk drive, keyboard or mouse, it's going to be slower than your program runs.  The OS is in control of this bottleneck.

You can make this more efficient by performing block reads, but more on this later.

**Bottleneck 2 - Text to internal representation**
The second bottleneck involves converting one or more characters into an internal number.  When dealing with text, there is no way around this; it must be done.

**Optimizing Text Numeric Input**
The fastest method to process text numbers from the input is to read the input into a large buffer and convert the text in memory to a number.

So, using C++ streams as an example:

```
const unsigned int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024u;
unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
cin.read((char *)buffer, BUFFER_SIZE); // Read 1k at a time.
```

The next step, coverting text to internal representation, has many possibilities.
I suggest using `std::istringstream`.

**Reading from cin**
When reading from `cin`, all optimizations can be thrown in the trash.  Your waiting time for the User to enter a number is so huge compared to the processor's execution times that optimization won't gain you any significance.  For example, if I optimize your program to save you 100 milliseconds, the User won't see any effect because the user is taking thousands of milliseconds to enter a number (even at high typing speeds of 60 words per minute). If you want faster processing, you'll have to put the text into a file.

**Microoptimizations**
This kind of optimization is called microoptimizations.  You may be optimizing an area of code that is not as executed as much as another area.  Also, if you make changes to your program, the optimization could be wrecked.

Concentrate on correctness and robustness before you optimize.

Comment: Using `cin` does not necessarily mean it is going to be input by a human though.

Comment: @Rufflewind You're right. And in my case there are some sequences of integers already existing before running the program. The test looks similar to ideone.com where after pasting code you can paste stdin which mght be of any desired length and complexity. Then just run the program does (or not) its job.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Thank U very much, that was an answer I've looked for so long! But there're details about input that make my problem more specific. Namely, the input is in ideone.com style so before runtime there already exists a long long number of integers already waiting for me. I've got to read each of them and in the meantime do several operations on them but of complexity O(n). So the while loop seems best solution. But how to change  
<br>`while(cin) { //operations on a single int }`  
into your stream like function? What has to the while loop look like?

Comment: @vladimir1923: Again, your bottleneck is getting data into memory. You could also reduce some execution by supplying your own buffer, search the web for "istream::rdbuf".

Comment: @vladimir1923: There are many functions to convert numeric text in a buffer to internal representation: `atoi, strtol, istringstream, sscanf`, etc.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Ok, thank U for more info, so if I got You right I can produce multinumeric integers like (3425535) reading single chars using getChar()? But could You explain me the mechanism of that kind of operation? After reading a single char I can use `int n = atoi(c)` with 'c' as a char, but how to join separate chars into one and then make an in out of it?